# Linting with PHP CLI does not display errors but does let you know there is one

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

PHP linter (`php -l`) does know show errors in CLI on Windos.

```
C:\websites\Project>"\Program Files (x86)\PHP5.3\php.exe" -l test.php
Errors parsing test.php
```

But does not display error messages.

I turned on both:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Luckly i was able to find it in my logs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\temp\php-errors.log

Error:

    [03-Jan-2016 16:24:24 America/New_York] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in test.php on line 3
```

**PS. This is about why the error did not display**

Error was: I used `$var = [1];` instead of `$var = array(1);`.

This was intentionally, I am trying to figure out why CLI `php -l` is not working for other projects so I used a test file as a control.

Comment: So, what is there in test.php on line 3?

Comment: I used $var = [1];  instead of $var = array(1);  Keep in mind that this is a test file. I have many other files I have to validate.

Comment: Short array syntax (`[]`) introduced in php5.4

Comment: Yes, keep in mind this is about Windows CLI PHP -l linter not displaying in STDOUT

Comment: Try running under `cygwin`. What are you using, `cmd.exe` or PowerShell?

Comment: I am using `cmd.exe` Also , same thing happened in `powershell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the variable `display_errors` to be "on" or "1" on the command line.

The way to do it is using the `-d` option of php command line interpreter.

For example:

`php -l -d display_errors=1 test.php`

or

`php -l -d display_errors=On test.php`